# Creating an item based on text in a cell of a DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, visual-studio-lightswitch

In a LightSwitch application I have the following three tables:
[image: Tables: Post, Tag, PostTag]

These tables are part of a bigger, already existing database that cannot be modified for this application.

I also have the following grid on the details page of a Post:
[image: Grid details]

What's shown is the 'Tag' property of PostTag, filtered for just one Post.

So far so good. However, because there can be a lot of different tags, I want to allow users to create a new tag by simply typing in a non-existing tag into the AutoCompleteBox and then, in some way, create a new tag with the entered value.

I have found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/08/16/how-to-allow-adding-of-data-to-an-auto-complete-drop-down-box-in-lightswitch.aspx) blog post by Beth Massi explaining how one could do something like this, but the solution is for just a single AutoCompleteBox. It looks absolutely terrible in a DataGrid, because the button will be shown in all rows and I have not managed to find a way to disable them conditionally (in a DataGrid).

Another acceptable solution would be [this one using a message box and LostFocus](http://dotnettim.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/lightswitch-add-non-existent-records-using-autocompletebox/), but it, too, does not seem to play nice with a DataGrid.

Is there a way to get what I want, or do I have to add some other way of easily creating new Tags?